# 101: What does baseApp = (MyApp)this.getContext() do?

Tags: java, android, oop, constructor, instance

When I do this:

```
 baseApp = (MyApp)this.getContext();
```

What am I actually doing?

as opposed to doing:

```
 baseApp = myApp.doSomething();
```

I'm not concern with the methods but understanding the construction.
How are those 2 above different and why?

Whats the meaning of doing (MyApp)?

Comment: You are not using a constructor in either case.

Comment: It indicates the casting of your `Context` variable which used in `MyApp` class when you created a instance of it.

Comment: ok that's one thing i learned. can you expounded on more or give more direction.

Comment: (MyApp) is [type-casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: nice. type casting! btw that oracle docs is way to terse to learn from. thanks for the direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whats the meaning of doing (MyApp)?

It is a reference type cast.

It checks that the reference produced by evaluating the RHS (i.e. `this.getContext()` ) is compatible with `MyApp` and then uses it that as the result of the expression (with that type).  If the reference given by the RHS expression is not for a compatible type, a runtime exception will be thrown.

By contrast ...

```
  baseApp = myApp.doSomething();
```

is just calling the `doSomething()` method and assigning it ... WITHOUT doing a typecast.  If the `doSomething()` method does not deliver a value of the correct type, you will get a compilation error.

---

For the record, there is no "instantiation" going on here.  Instantiation is done using the `new` operator<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - ... or by calling specific reflective methods.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly where are you calling this from? An `Activity`?

The first line is casting the current objects context to a `MyApp` object then assigning it to an object named `baseApp`. And I also assume `baseApp` is of type `MyApp`.

The second line is assigning the value returned from the method named `doSomething()` to `baseApp`

---

but more information is needed to compare further.